# How do I check if my scope variable actually contains NaN?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do i check if my scope variable actually contains NaN?

`isNaN($scope.variable)` returns true even if `$scope.variable == undefined.`

I want to set `form validity` true if scope variable actually contains `NaN` but not `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the problem is that [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) converts argument to Number type if it's not a number already, and since `ToNumber(undefined)` is indeed `NaN` you get this behavior.

So you can [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) which was introduced in ES2015 to fix this confusion or add additional check whether the value is of Number type, so basically polyfilling this `Number.isNaN`:

```
$scope.variable == undefined.
// ...
typeof $scope.variable == 'number' && isNaN($scope.variable); // => false
```